# Why would [RequireHttps] cause SimpleMembership to look for SQLEXPRESS in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, https, security, simplemembership

I have a very simple ASP.NET MVC 4 application which is published to Azure. When publishing, I let Visual Studio replace the `DefaultConnection` with a connection string to an Azure SQL Database. If I have a class and restrict it to certain roles, this works fine, e.g.

```
//[RequireHttps]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
[Authorize(Roles = "canEditThings")]
public class ThingController : Controller
{
    // <stuff goes here>
}
```

But, if I uncomment the `RequireHttps` attribute, I'm suddenly faced with this error :

```
SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: 

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance 
using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.
```

This has only started happening recently. Prior to a couple of weeks ago, this all worked.

Any ideas?